# CALayer custom drawing glitch

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics, calayer

I'm working on glow effect **CALayer**. I've created an `UIView` category. And my custom drawing gives me this strange animation:

[image]

Please, check my [full code.](https://gist.github.com/orkenstein/55aaba40f4bcfe78fa36)

**UPDATE:**
I've added some code, that I think crucial.

```
- (void)setGlowHidden:(BOOL)glowHidden {
  self.layer.masksToBounds = glowHidden;
  self.clipsToBounds = glowHidden;
  if (self.glowLayer == nil) {
    self.glowLayer = [GlowLayer layer];
    self.glowLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds;
    self.glowLayer.parentView = self;
    self.glowLayer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.glowLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter;
    [self.layer addSublayer:self.glowLayer];
  }
  //...
  [self.glowLayer setNeedsDisplay];
  [self.glowLayer performSelector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}

//...

- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
  CGFloat delta = MAX(self.glowSize, self.innerGlowSize);
  CGRect drawingRect = CGRectMake(-delta, -delta, CGRectGetWidth(self.parentView.frame) + 2 * delta,
                                  CGRectGetHeight(self.parentView.frame) + 2 * delta);
  CGPoint offsetPoint = CGPointMake(-drawingRect.origin.x, -drawingRect.origin.y);
  self.frame = drawingRect;
  [self setNeedsLayout];
  [self layoutIfNeeded];

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(drawingRect.size, NO, 0.0f);

//  [self.parentView drawViewHierarchyInRect:rect afterScreenUpdates:YES];
  [self.parentView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *textImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
  CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
  if (_glowSize > 0) {
    CGContextSetShadow(ctx, CGSizeZero, _glowSize);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, CGSizeZero, _glowSize, _glowColor.CGColor);
  }
  [textImage drawAtPoint:offsetPoint];

  CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
  //...
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code (the smallest possible subset that reproduces this problem) *directly* in the question.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist, take a look, please.

Comment: Performing layout in `drawInContext:` is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be simpler to just set the shadow properties of the parent layer directly?  (`shadowRadius`, `shadowOpacity`, etc.)

Comment: @robmayoff, yes, possible. Removing these lines gives the same. My goal is to make glowing based on content. I don't want dropping shadow around square frame.